# Update single document in mongodb using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new in node and mongodb and I am trying to update the user password in the mongo database using node. I am getting the following error --

`errmsg: 'After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId(\'5a4f50381a1152ec09277578\') , ...}, the (immutable) field \'_id\' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId(\'5a739493c592356f1b5a78b6\')'` }

My code in `models/accounts.js` is

```
AccountSchema.static('passchange', function (password, callback) {
var that = this;
if (typeof userobj!="undefined") {
        console.log("User Object");
        console.log(userobj._id); //I am getting the user id here

        that.findOne({_id:userobj._id}, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                console.log("No User");
                return callback(null, false);
            }
            else
            {
                var salt = this.salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

                var updatepwd = new that({
                    salt: salt,
                    hash: hash
                });
                var conditions = { _id: userobj._id }
                that.updateOne(conditions,updatepwd, function (err, savePassword) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log("err");
                        console.log(err);
                        return callback({err: err}, false);
                    } else {
                        console.log("savePassword._id");
                        console.log(savePassword._id);
                        //return callback(null, {_id : savePassword._id});
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of "this?"  And what is a "new" that?  Those names aren't very descriptive.

Comment: Are you certain that `updatepwd` shouldn't be `{ '$set': { salt: salt, hash: hash } }` instead? My understanding is that you're simply overwriting the entire document as opposed to updating specific values. The `$set` operator would fix this problem.

Comment: @B.Fleming Now working. Great. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of documenting the solution:

As per the discussion in the comments, the problem appeared to be that the original document was being completely overwritten by the update, as opposed to only the `hash` and `salt` fields being updated. The appropriate fix was to update the `updatepwd` value to the following:

```
var updatepwd: { $set: {
    salt: salt,
    hash: hash
}};
```

The `$set` operator ensures that only `salt` and `hash` get updated, and thus the `_id` field (along with the rest of the data) remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to update the new operator because you are producing a new ID when you don't intend to change the ID, just the password.  Try to follow the logic below instead of the new operator.

```
items.forEach(function (product) { //update or create new products

// Es6 assign
var productToUpdate = {};
productToUpdate = Object.assign(productToUpdate, product._doc);
delete productToUpdate._id;

Product.findOneAndUpdate({product_id: product.product_id}, productToUpdate, 
                     {upsert: true}, function (err) {
if (err)  return updateDBCallback(err);
   updateDBCallback(null, 'saved');
});
});
```